# Selecting out the subset combinations from a Set in java

Tags: set, combinations, subset

Let's say I have a Set s and I want all subsets of s that can be made from two elements of s.  Is there a package I can use or a best practice you can recommend?

Note:  I want the sets (combinations), not all permutations with an order.

The case for two elements is kind of easy and I figure I'll order the elements and use two loops to make the combinations.  However if there is something more elegant or more extensible that I could use, I'd like to hear about about it.

Comment: A concrete example:  Let's say I have a deck of cards and I deal two cards.  I want something that will list all the possible hands you can have (without regard to the order that you where dealt them.)

Answer (score 0):

Find [powerset](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Power_Set#Java) of s excluding those two elements and add those two elements in all the resulting sets

Comment: I believe you have misunderstood.  I want the elements of the power set that have a length of two elements.  I might do something similar to that code, but I will not find an entire power set because finding a whole power set takes exponential time.  I'm going to add an example to the question.

Comment: I don't think there is something more elegant and simpler than using 2 loops, since n*(n-1) combinations are possible